# Change record type error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY

Tags: trigger, record

```
trigger ChangeRecordType on Product2 (after update) {
   for(Product2 product: Trigger.new) {
      if(product.Available_for_lease__c == false) {
        product.RecordTypeId = 'Products Archive';     
        }
 }
```

This is my code for trigger updateleaseforhide

trigger UpdateLeaseForHide on Opportunity ( After update) {

```
Opportunity[] wonOpps = new Opportunity[0];
    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.StageName == 'closed won') {
            wonOpps.add(record);
        }
    }
        if(wonOpps.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
   Product2[] products = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :wonOpps)];
   for(Product2 product: products) {
     product.Available_for_Lease__c = false;
   }
    update products;
```

}

My code above was to change the record type of my product into 'product archive' but when i tested it, there was an error. BTW, I also have a trigger for updateleaseforhide that will uncheck the checkbox on the products object via status 'closed won' in the opportunities object.

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger UpdateLeaseForHide caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: UpdateLeaseForHide: execution of
>   AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First
>   exception on row 0 with id 01t61000000eZwTAAU; first error:
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, ChangeRecordType: execution of
>   AfterUpdate caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: Products
>   Archive Trigger.ChangeRecordType: line 4, column 1: []:
>   Trigger.UpdateLeaseForHide: line 16, column 1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In given line:

> product.RecordTypeId = 'Products Archive';

You should pass **RecordType ID** not its name. It should look like this:

```
product.RecordTypeId = '124000000043deAeYc';
```

Or you can use Sobject describe to get ID dynamically

```
product.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Product2.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Product Archive').getRecordTypeId();
```

Comment: where can i find the id for my record type?

Comment: @gelay upfated my answer. You can find record Type ID on Product2 sobject definition' record type section. Or dynamically just by passing record Type Developer Name

Comment: if im going to use record type id, where can i find it?

Comment: It is mentioned in the answer from @Ashwani it is this line product.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Product2.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Product Archive').getRecordTypeId();

Comment: I have already changed it but the error still persists.. i think it has to do with my updateleaseforhide trigger..

Comment: You should get different error not the same. Like you have passed wrong record type name or something other than record type is wrong. @gelay

Answer (score 0):

I have already figured it out. Instead of creating another trigger, I inserted this  trigger into updateleaseforhide so that when the product is updated, the triggers will be activated. I think the error is that after the update in the first trigger, it will be forced to update again because of the second trigger. 
Anyways thanks for your help guys :)

```
    trigger UpdateLeaseForHide on Opportunity ( After update) {
    Opportunity[] wonOpps = new Opportunity[0];
    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.StageName == 'closed won') {
            wonOpps.add(record);
        }
    }
        if(wonOpps.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
   Product2[] products = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :wonOpps)];
   for(Product2 product: products) {
     product.Available_for_Lease__c = false;  
     product.RecordTypeId = '01261000000GpJt';     
     }
    update products;
     }
```